# How can I return once all child http requests complete in a parent http request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm hitting an API which returns all details on kills in a game, the first endpoint returns an id to the kill event, then a second endpoint is hit to retrieve the killer and killed names.

Because of the way this API is set up I need to make a request to first get the event ID and then wait for all id's in the returned array to get a result and then process the entire kill array:

```
    requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var events = [];
        if (response.body && response.body.length > 0) {
            data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('events')) {
                events = data.events.map(function(event) {
                    return this.getDataForHeroKillId(event.id, function(killInfo) {
                        return { killer: killInfo.killer, killed: killInfo.killed, timestamp: event.time };
                    });
                }.bind(this));
                console.log('events is: ', events);
            }
        }
        return Promise.all(events);
    }.bind(this));
```

My getKillInformation function looks like this:

```
KillFeed.prototype.getKillInformation = function(id, cb) {
var data = null;
    requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var event = {};
        if (response.body && response.body.length > 0) {
            data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('Killer')) {
                event = { killer: data.Killer, killed: data.Killed};
            }
        }
        cb(event);
    });
};
```

In the second method I was hoping that I could callback the result of each child request and then once they had all been executed my new array would hold the data.  But due to the event driven nature of JS I found that my code block continues to return an empty events array as this code is obviously non blocking (understandably as blocking the event queue whilst making a HTTP request is not ideal).  How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One uses [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this.

```
requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
    var events = [];

    if (response.body && response.body.length > 0) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('events')) {
            // Trying to process the kill information here
            events = data.events.map(function(event) {
                return this.getKillInformation(event.id).then(function(killInfo) {
                    return { killer: killInfo.killer, killed: killInfo.killed, timestamp: event['time1'] };
                });
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }

    return Promise.all(events);
});

KillFeed.prototype.getKillInformation = function(id) {
    var url = 'internal_url';
    return requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
        if (response.body && response.body.length > 0) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('killer')) {
                return { killer: data.Killer, killed: data.Killed };
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however in my `events.map` loop, it resolves to [undefined, undefined, undefined]; because it returns that item before the HTTP request is resolved, meaning `return Promise.all` returns the array `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`  any thing else I can do?

Comment: @Alex events it contains undefined, instead of a promise because your conditions do not fulfil - `getKillInformation` response.body length is 0, or it has no property *killer*. No value is returned, or by default, undefined is returned.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that I need to make `.getKillInformation` a promise so Promise.all knows when to resolve or reject, is thast correct?  With the current set up, when the callback from `getKillInformation` is called, the info is printed as expected in the `.map` function, but I see that the events array is returned before the map event finishes

Comment: @Alex Ah, just noticed. your `event` object is always empty. You never actually set it from your response. `var event = {}`

Comment: Updated to reflect your suggestions, still doesn't work.   Does `getKilInformation` not need to be a Promise for Promise.all to work?

Comment: `requestify.then()` returns a promise, so `getKilInformation` also returns a promise. I updated my answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118822/discussion-between-alex-and-kaspars).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) and its waterfall method. Async is a NodeJS module, but it can be used in browser, too.